# Apache fronting Tomcat - redirect url

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite

First of all, I'm new to apache/tomcat technology so I don't expect that You will give me direct answer. I'd rather recieve a hints how to resolve my issue and also to learn something new :) So, here it goes.

I've got apache and tomcat installed on my host. Tomcat is serving application X. Application X is available through two urls:

`http://app_name/`

and it has its own modules under (for example)

`http://app_name/app_module`

Now, I need to redirect the traffic, so that each person that enters `http://app_name` will be redirected (without change of the url) to `http://app_name/app_module`.

I'm trying to achieve that using `mod_rewrite` module but it doesn't seems to work (most of the examples were taken from stackoverflow).

Comment: What did you actually try?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to redirect without change URL, maybe see mod_rewrite with [P] flag ( proxy)

Comment: Hello. I've tried to use mod_rewrite with options:
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteRule http://app_name/ http://app_name/app_module [P]`

Doesn't seem to work. I still keep getting to the *app_name url.

Comment: You can use also proxyPass like this :

`ProxyRequests     off 
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass / http://app_name/app_module  
ProxyPassReverse / http://app_name/app_module `

Add this lines in your virtualhost apache,

But I have a question, tomcat listen on witch port ?

Comment: Using netstat -anp | grep `pid` I get the following ports (described as LISTEN): 8099, 8005, 8009, 8080, 8443. As for proxyPass, I've configured my httpd.conf file this way:

`<VirtualHost *:80> Proxyrequests off ProxyPreserverHost on ProxyPass / http://app_name/app_module/ ProxyPassReverse / http://app_name/app_module/ </VirtualHost>`

Restarted apache, but still the same output. I wonder what am i missing here.

Comment: Add serverName directive in virtualhost : `ServerName www.example.com`.

In line describe proxy rules, is app_name  formated like this :  localhost:8080 ?

Comment: For proxy pass it is: `ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/` On this same port Tomcat is awaiting for connections. Adding ServerName did not change anything.

Comment: Have you define AJP connector in tomcat configuration file 
/etc/tomcat7/server.xml : 

`<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />`

Comment: Using `ProxyPass` to rewrite the URL space of your Java web application is a recipe for disaster. What's wrong with putting your web application under "/app" and proxying the whole URL space?

Comment: @billyjoe25 yes. It's configured in exact same way that you have posted

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz unfortunatelly, application is not mine and it uses its own Tomcat, so there is no way to put it under /app and even, for each configuration update i have to dig for it

Comment: @billyjoe25 I found something. I've noticed that application is adding additional entry in the url so it looks like `http://app_name/app_module/app_module` but the direct link for the app is `http://app_name/app_module`. I've corrected ProxyPass to be like this: `ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/app_module/` and now when I try to enter it, I'm redirected to correct webpage. Now another issue occured - providing correct credentials - I'm keep getting back to the login page. When I disable ProxyPass - I can login normally.

Comment: Also, In logs I can see, that using the desired solution, I'm missing one /app_module/ in the requests, so probably this is causing issues.